# export flex datagrid to excel,which is better to implements with java or flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, actionscript

with the platform j2ee,data of datagrid is from java dao(from the database),so which way is better,to export the data of datagrid to Excel with java dao or flex?thx, and forget my poor English...

Answer (score 0):

your real qestion is where it have more support.
in flex the for me i found 2 solutions for this problem:

1. is using the action script library as3xls
   http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/ - it export a real excel document but it have a cons
   it from my expirent with him it support only english chars it's not export unicoded chars
2. is saving a feak xls file that contain an html table format yes it works!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the server-side implementation approach. In the company I'm working we tried both (but okay it was .NET). By now we had so many problems with the export of documents (also PDF [isn't it ironic??]) in combination with Flex. I remember following problems:

- you might need a more current version of your Flash plugin (>= 10.0) (could cause legacy problems)
- there were problems specifying different data types like dates
- in the end it took more man-days than intended

A server side implementation might be more effort (in the first step), but

- Java is more powerful
- it's faster
- more configuration is possible
- (garbage collection works a lot better)

Answer (score 0):

I've also dealt with this issue with my flex app on whether to do the datagrid export on the client side or server side.

I had originally exported the datagrid on the client side using as3xls (as mentioned above). It worked well at first, but then started giving me real headaches once it's limitations were reached (aka not being able to export non ASCII characters). This is when I stopped using as3xls.

If you do not require the datagrid export have any specific formatting, another option would be to export the datagrid contents to a comma delimited string and save the string to a CSV file, all from within the client. This way you avoid issues with specific data types (dates), have complete control over the text exported, and write out to a really loose and flexible file format. And you save yourself having to code the infrastructure to round-trip the datagrid contents to your server and back in cases where the size and formatting of exported data may not really justify it.

If you do require formatting or the vastly superior power of java to handle your export, I would suggest using an MS Office API like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to give you the ability to format your data much better into standard XLS or XLSX documents. This ended up being the solution we went with (except we are using SmartXLS as our Excel API), for the greater ability to control exactly how the data exported was to be laid out and formatted, plus delivering XLS/XLSX files to clients is more professional, and it's easier to provide to those less computer savvy clients than is a CSV.